# How to make conditional formatting or macro based on a number from a different tab/sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

How can I make conditional formatting/ a macro/ some sort of code in Google Sheets that can take a number from Sheet A cell `F3`, read it and if it has a `5` in it then in Sheet B colour cells `E4:I6` in colour yellow.
But when it reads it if the number has a `0` then in Sheet B it colours cells `J4:N6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 points in your question you need to do.

1. **In conditional formatting when referring to a range in another tab/sheet you have to use the function [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)**
2. You will need 2 rules. One for each range (`E4:I6` and `J4:N6`)

You apply the following formulas to the ranges by choosing `Custom formula is`

For range `E4:I6` in `Sheet B`

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet A'!F3")=5
```

For range `J4:N6` in `Sheet B`

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet A'!F3")="0"
```

Comment: I tried both of these, neither of them worked. Also for the second piece of code, for J4:N6, I mean to say if a 0 (zero) is in F3 then it colours the range in Sheet B.

Comment: *"...for J4:N6, I mean to say if a 0 (zero) is in F3"* Still. It should work. Please share a test sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l4dKqGaKD8FdIASJoOtiXOXmwV5NPhh4rmQm4BuONDs/edit?usp=sharing Here is a test sheet.

Comment: Your sheet is private. You need to make it public.

Comment: Sorry, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l4dKqGaKD8FdIASJoOtiXOXmwV5NPhh4rmQm4BuONDs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It works fine. Please check your sheet. Just make sure you name sheets and ranges **correctly**.

Comment: Hey, thank you! So does this work with numbers such as 60 or 35 or 75, etc? If not how can I make it work with those numbers? Also I thought it might be because of the sheet names, I will need to change the names of the sheet, when I do change the names what do I need to do?

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you. It does not work with 60, or 70 but does work with 0. Is there any way to alter the code to make it work with 60, 70, and numbers that end with 0?

Comment: 1. *"It does not work with 60, or 70 but does work with 0"* It works. Check your formulas for mistakes. 2. *"...make it work with ... numbers that end with 0"* This is a completely different question. Do start a new question. 3. Your question has been answered. Please accept it.