# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets for cells ending in certain number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two pieces of code in Google Sheets. They basically take data from cell `F3` in A sheet named `Data` and use it to colour cells in the next sheet named 'Template'. If the number in cell `F3` is a `0` then they colour cells `E4-I6` in 'Template'. If cell `F3` has a `5` in it then it will colour cells `J4 - N6` in 'Template'.

The problem is I need to alter this code so that if a number has `0` eg. 60,70, 180 or if a number has `5` eg. 65,75,85 then it colours the cells.

Here are my two pieces of code

`=INDIRECT("'Data'!F3")=5` then if it does have a `5` it will colour cells `J4 - N6`

`=INDIRECT("'Data'!F3")=0` then if it does have a `0` it will colour cells `E4 - I6`

Here is a link to the sheet if you need it: [My Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l4dKqGaKD8FdIASJoOtiXOXmwV5NPhh4rmQm4BuONDs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use these 2 rules

For numbers ending in `5` use

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXT(INDIRECT("'Data'!E3"),"#"),"[5]$")
```

For numbers ending in `0` use

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXT(INDIRECT("'Data'!E3"),"#"),"[0]$")
```

As mentioned in the [answer of your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64111622/1527780)

> In conditional formatting when referring to a range in another tab/sheet you have to use the function INDIRECT

Functions used:

- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)
- [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)